# How can we find difference between two tables using subquery in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I Want to Find the difference between two tables using subquery.
Query as follows:

```
Select emp.id   from Employee emp

Inner join Organization org on emp.id =org.empid 

Inner join Department dep on  emp.depart_id =dep.id
```

Where emp. Address ='City'

And emp. Date >= '2020-11-01'

```
Where emp.id not in 

(select * From Account 

Where Status ='Salaried')
```

I Want the empid not there in Account table.

Answer (score 0):

If everything else is OK (with your query), then

```
Where emp.id not in (select emp_id From Account Where Status ='Salaried') 
                            ------
                            EMP_ID, not *
```

Comment: Please check i have edited my code by adding one more requirement.

Comment: Although you've spoiled formatting, it seems you added another two WHERE conditions. So let them be. The final WHERE should be changed to AND (as you can't have two WHEREs).

Comment: Ok got,  but the table Account is in another db. How Shall i deals with that. Db name is Business _Intell

Comment: If it is another **database**, you have to use a **database link**.